# Rails: Access members of a collection in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I have a child object with an alternate partial form. Further to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16839921/1736461), I'm able to render the object using a partial form like this:

`<%= render 'child_items/alternate_partial', :collection => parent_item.child_items %>`

But I can't seem to access members of the collection in the partial. When I was using:

`<%= render parent_item.child_items %>`

the partial could just go `<%= child_item.property %>` and everything worked. But when I'm doing this the top way (and it seems that I have to, if I want to specify the partial), any reference to `child_item` throws a NameError. How do I get at the collection item inside the partial?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials in **3.4.5 Rendering Collections**:
*When a partial is called with a pluralized collection, then the individual instances of the partial have access to the member of the collection being rendered via a variable named after the partial.*

In this case, the partial is **_alternate_partial**, and within the **_alternate_partial** partial, you can refer to **alternate_partial** to get the instance that is being rendered.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, when I try to access things I get `undefined method 'some_method' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: Ensure ```parent_item.child_items``` is present and you call ```<%= alternate_partial.property %>``` inside **child_items/alternate_partial**. I've just tried it myself and it works like expected.

Comment: `parent_item.child_items` is definitely present in the originating page. There was even some wacky thing I did where I printed the whole thing as a hash, but it was happening in the originating page, not the partial. By the way, does it matter that the originating page is itself a partial?

I think I'm going to give up and render the child partials in the parent-partial. Makes it a one-stop-shop for the designers and stylers anyway. :-)